# How to find intersection point of a plot with x-axis in python?

Tags: python, graph, plot, intersection

I want to get the intersection point of a curve I plotted with the x-axis.
I don't have the equation of the curve. I only have the discrete values and I plotted them. Is there a way to do this easily with python?
The code is simple:

```
    incident_angles = np.linspace(0,90,91)
    r_p = np.array(r_p_list) 
    #r_p_list contains fresnel coefficients for the incident angles
    py.plot(incident_angles,abs(r_p))
```

Now when I plot this, the curve intersects with the x-axis at a point which is the brewster angle. I want to get this point. 
The graph should look like the blue curve in this image:
[fresnel coefficients for reflected TM polarized light](http://physics-animations.com/Physics/English/raysfig2.gif)
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: No I don't want someone to write the code for me but I just felt my description was enough. instead of writing long question, I just wanted to write it in a simple way. I tried to find a solution for the problem but all the solutions I found depend that I have the equation for the curve I want to get the intersection for. And I thought maybe there is an easier way that  I don't know to do this with python.

Comment: Why don't you just search through `r_p` for the element with the smallest absolute value?

Comment: Because the intersection point (angle) does not necessarily correspond toone of the r_p values I have. it could be a value in between two angles and  this is the case here actually.it should be 57.3229 but the r_p values I have correspond to 57,58.. degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I know how.
First,We can use "scipy.interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial" to create a function defined by the discrete data and then use "fsolve" to find the roots (x-axis intersection)

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

x = incident_angles
y1 = r_p
func = interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial(x,y1[:,np.newaxis])
brewster = fsolve(func, 0.0)  #0.0 is the starting point (angle)
print brewster
```